# Dealing with spatie asynchronous error handling

Tags: php, asynchronous

I'm working on an asynchronous process on a PHP project. I'm using a library named [spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async). The code snippet is like below :

```
foreach (range(1, 2) as $i) {
    $pool->add(function () use ($i) {
        // Do a thing
        try {
            $result = $i / 0; // This will cause an error
            return "Works";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return -1;
        }
    })->then(function ($output) {
        // Handle success
        echo (output . "\n");
    })->catch(function ($exception) {
        // When an exception is thrown, it's caught and passed here.
        echo "Sounds good, but don't work\n";
    })
}

$pool->wait();
```

All I want is when the `$result` got an error, it will go into the inner `catch`, but instead, it goes down to the bottom catch which causing a different result from what I want.

The result that I want is :

> -1
>
> -1

But instead, the result is :

> Sounds good, but don't work
>
> Sounds good, but don't work

Can anyone help me to achieve the result as I want?

Comment: What kind of exception type is `\e`…?! That's probably not matching the exception being thrown…

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code is, that it does not throw an Exception in the add method call. A division by 0 is just causing an error, but not ein exception. Instead of changing the whole php error handler, I 'd suggest to extend your logic a little bit in your add method call.

```
$divisor = 0;
$pool->add(function() use ($i, $divisor) {
    try {
        if ($divisor === 0) {
             throw new \LogicException('Division by zero!');
        }

        return $i / $divisor;
    } catch (\LogicException $e) {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Another solution could be changing the error handling for the pool method call.

```
set_error_handler(function () {
    throw new \LogicException('Ouch!');
});

$pool->add(function() use ($i) {
    try {
        $result = $i / 0;
    } catch (\LogicException $e) {
        return -1;
    }
});

restore_error_handler();
```

Caution! Changing the error handler affects all upcoming errors. Even the errors thrown in your used library. Keep in mind, that these are code snippets. This is not tested or thougt to be used in production. Hope that helps out a little bit.